# errors: esami package short answer questions

Tags: errors, esami

I am using the [esami](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/esami) package to make a short answer exam.  According to the documentation, I can use the following code in the variants file:

This is the `eachtest.tex` file.

```
\begin{problem}
This is the question.
\begin{solution}
This is the answer.
\end{solution}
\end{problem}
```

This is the `problemtestfile.tex` that I am using to run it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[shufflerandom,autopston,xyz,twocolumns,solutions,fillb]{esami}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

% +=============================+
% |         DEFINITIONS         |
% +=============================+

\def\examname{The name of the exam}                                                                 
\def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2013/3/22}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading

\begin{document}
\testversioni

\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers

% +=============================+
% |       THE SEED              |
% +=============================+

\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}

\randomi=\seme
\permuta

\section*{Practice Final Exam}
\begin{test}
\begin{questions}
\esercizi{eachtest}
\end{questions}
\end{test}

\closevers
}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error:

```
eachtest.tex
6
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \end{problem}

esami.sty
534
Overfull \hbox (5.79999pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 534--534
[][]
```

I don't understand what keeps causing it - maybe a package option I am missing?  I tried to tag this question with the `esami` package, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that create the problem:

1. in the eachtest.tex file, the environment `problem` must be enclosed in the command `\newproblem`, as follows

   ```
   \newproblem{
   \begin{problem}
   This is the question.
   \begin{solution}
   This is the answer.
   \end{solution}
   \end{problem}}
   ```
2. in the problemtestfile.tex, exercises within a `problem` environment must be used *outside* the `test` and  `question` environments:

   ```
   \section*{Practice Final Exam}
   \esercizi{eachtest}
   ```

Comment: beautiful...worked like a charm