# How to create an exam using esami package?

Tags: esami

I'm trying to get randomization of multiple choice questions on latex to work. I learned about the package `esami` and it's what I'm looking for, but I can't even get the package to work!

In a 39 line document, I get error codes for lines 500+ which don't even exist so it's leaving me rather confused. I'm probably just starting the document wrong but if someone could help me out it would be much appreciated. Here's one of several things I've tried (just trying to see how it works, once it I do I'm pretty sure I can figure it out from there)

```
\documentclass[english]{exam}
\usepackage[allowrandomize]{esami}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}

\begin{questions}

\newproblem{
\item \PTs{1} The solutions of the equation
\[x^2-5x+6=0\]
are
\begin{answers}{2}
\bChoices[random]
\Ans0 $x=3$ e $x=-2$ \eAns
\Ans0 $x=-3$ e $x=-2$ \eAns
\Ans1 $x=3$ e $x=2$ \eAns
\eFreeze
\Ans0 none of the other answers is correct \eAns
\eChoices
\end{answers}
}
\newproblem{
\item \PTs{1} The solutions of the equation
\[x^2+5x+6=0\]
are
\begin{answers}{2}
\bChoices[random]
\Ans0 $x=3$ e $x=-2$ \eAns
\Ans1 $x=-3$ e $x=-2$ \eAns
\Ans0 $x=3$ e $x=2$ \eAns
\eFreeze
\Ans0 none of the other answers is correct \eAns
\eChoices
\end{answers}
}

\end{questions}

\end{test}

\end{document}
```

The code for the question was taken directly out of the instruction manual for the package `esami` so I'm led to believe that I'm making a rookie mistake in starting the document.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this question helps (or not): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114845/errors-esami-package-short-answer-questions

Comment: First major error.  Do not call on exam class but use the article class.  Reason: esami loads the exam definitions.  So your line 500 error is due to the commands being defined twice.    However there are still errors so look carefully at Segletes  comment.

Answer (score 1):

@R.Schumacher is right: you must not use the `exam`class with the esami packaage, but the `article` class. Moreover, exercises must be written in separate files, each one containing the chosen number of variants. And I think you miss also the configuration file.
I suggest you try first with the sample files that are contained in the doc folder of the package (test-A.tex and the exercises files). Once you get them to work, you will be able to make any change you need.

Comment: The documentation of `esami` is not so good for users to follow. It is better to provide some examples in the documentation to make the explanation more understandable. Thank you!

Comment: @Anonymous, there are a lot of examples both in the doc file (english and italian) and in the doc folder (files with examples of tests, exercises, etc.). What kind of examples do you think we shall add? Thank you!